# MATLAB: how to reuse plot options?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following plot:

```
patch('Vertices',rocket_point_cloud,'Faces',rocket_faces,...
      'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none',...
      'BackFaceLighting','reverselit',...
      'SpecularStrength',1,'DiffuseStrength',1)
```

I would like to reuse the plot options, i.e. reuse:

```
'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none',...
          'BackFaceLighting','reverselit',...
          'SpecularStrength',1,'DiffuseStrength',1
```

Is it somehow possible to store the above in a variable, e.g. `my_options` and later on do:

```
patch('Vertices',other_cloud,'Faces',other_faces,my_options)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Just define your options in a [cell array](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html),

```
my_options = {'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none',...
      'BackFaceLighting','reverselit',...
      'SpecularStrength',1,'DiffuseStrength',1};
```

and then expand that cell array into a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) via curly-brace indexing:

```
patch('Vertices', rocket_point_cloud, 'Faces', rocket_faces, my_options{:})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did it